# Spring boot application with multiple PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer beans resolves to default value of property instead of configured value

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application where I am injecting values into a bean using the `@Value("${placeholder-config-path:default-value}")`. I am observing that each time the default-value is loaded for the property instead of resolving the placeholder-config-path from the configs. When I don't provide the default value, the correct value is loaded.

Upon researching this issue I found out it can occur when multiple `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` beans are present in the application context. I checked the beans that are getting generated using the `/actuator/beans` path and noticed there are two instances of the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean with the same id and singleton scope.

Upon debugging the code during runtime I am noticing that the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean (spring-beans v5.2.27) is resolving the placeholder path only if the default value is not provided. The `ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders` flag is set to `true`, therefore, ideally despite having multiple configurer beans the placeholder should eventually be resolved.

If the multiple instances of the configurer bean is indeed the root cause, how can I resolve this ? I am not explicitly creating these beans. They may be getting instantiated as I am loading configs from Spring cloud as well from local application.yml. Is there a way I can combine the two instances ? I can temporarily solve this problem by not using default values, however I would ideally like to be able to use default values.

EDIT:
Following is a part of the response from the /actuator/beans endpoint:
As part of the /actuator/beans response I see the following:

```
{
"contexts": {
    "my-service-1": {
        "beans": {
            
            "propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer": {
                "aliases": [],
                "scope": "singleton",
                "type": "org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer",
                "resource": "class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/context/PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.class]",
                "dependencies": []
            }
        
    },
    "bootstrap": {
        "beans": {
            
            
            "propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer": {
                "aliases": [],
                "scope": "singleton",
                "type": "org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer",
                "resource": "class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/context/PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.class]",
                "dependencies": []
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: There cannot be multiple beans with the same id. They are unique. How have you configured things in your application?

Comment: @M.Deinum I have updated the answer with the response from /actuator/beans. The two beans are in different contexts.

Comment: Those are indeed 2 due to Spring Cloud, however the first one is only used very early in the Spring Cloud bootstrapping phase. Now there is a hierarchy in these and it could be that, depending on the type of your bean, it is loaded very early on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out one of the dependency jars introduces an instance of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer through xml configuration. Whenever a placeholder was needed to be resolved, the request was going to this instance of the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer which did not have the required placeholder configuration. Therefore, it always resolved to default.
I don't need the jar anymore therefore I have removed the dependency which fixed this issue.